# Shall I quote the references that a quote refers to?

Tags: discussion, references

E.g. in a question I am writing, I want to quote a webpage:

> Phytobezoars may be hard to diagnose [1]
>   
> [...]
>   [1] Krausz, Michael M., et al. "Surgical aspects of gastrointestinal persimmon phytobezoar treatment." The American journal of surgery 152.5 (1986): 526-530.

On this Stack Exchange website, shall I just quote the text:

> Phytobezoars may be hard to diagnose [1]

or should I also quote the reference:

> Phytobezoars may be hard to diagnose [1]
>   
> [...]
>   [1] Krausz, Michael M., et al. "Surgical aspects of gastrointestinal persimmon phytobezoar treatment." The American journal of surgery 152.5 (1986): 526-530.

?

Answer (score 1):

I think just the link is sufficient unless you think the link is likely to disappear (news sites, discussion sites, unknowns, etc). Most academic journals and other sources of published research aren't likely to go anywhere so just a link is sufficient.

Comment: Does this mean I should copy the references iff the link is not an academic journal? What do you mean by other sources of published research? If that includes researchers' websites, I disagree, those tend to disappear fairly often.

Comment: Yeah, an individual researcher's site is likely to be an ephemeral one so I would cite the full details. But if they published and you can find the article on the journal's site or on an aggregating site like pubmed, then I don't think those sites are going anywhere.

Comment: How about text that is not part of an article?

Comment: Link rot has been a big problem on other sites and there is no reason to suggest that it won't be here.

Answer (score 1):

While I generally agree with @CareyGregory I want to make a strong mention of the use of [DOI links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier).  Most professional sources use them, and you will find them as the link listed in PubMed if it's not hosted by PubMed.  PubMed itself commits to a DOI standard so linking to their abstracts is also absolute.

Comment: Thanks, does this mean I should quote the references (using DOIs) that a quote refers to?

Comment: Unless the source is not available in electronic format, I would think providing the link itself is sufficient.

Comment: One link for each reference?

Comment: DOI's can't die, that's the point.  If it's a non-DOI source, and you have the time to, then yes I think it would be great to include the full reference.  I don't however, think we should try to make it a requirement as it will increase the effort needed to correctly answer a question, and therefore reduce the number of answers people are willing to give.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I also want to point out that there are ocassional reasons to site paper resources.  In my ["ideal" question](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/how-do-i-determine-a-target-time-frame-for-breastfeeding) to make space for the tour (which requires no links) I purposefully cited two "conflicting" pamphlets.  WHO documents are easy to refer to, but don't actually keep to a DOI standard, which is a good example of where the full citation could help.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Some how I thought your comment said something else?  Anyway, yes, I think one for each reference.